# Can we add the percentages of two groups?

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have the findings of a survey according to which the percentage of women who live in Paris is lower than that of men. That also applies for the women who live in Rome. Is it correct to say that the total percentage of women who live in both cities is lower than the percentage of men? Thank you in advance!

Comment: While Evariste's answer is correct, note that this is in essence only true because you're comparing against a _fixed_ number (1/2); it would be possible, for instance, for Paris to have a higher percentage of women than Naples and Nice to have a higher percentage of women than Rome, but still have (Paris+Nice) have a _lower_ percentage of women than (Rome+Naples).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that the total percentage of women who live in both cities is lower than the percentage of men?

Yes. (Assuming "both" means living in one or the other, not the two at the same time)

$\frac{f_1}{m_1}<\frac 12$ and $\frac{f_2}{m_2}<\frac 12 \rightarrow \frac{f_1+f_2}{m_1+m_2}=\frac{f_1}{m_1+m_2}+\frac{f_2}{m_1+m_2}<\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{m_2}{m_1})}+\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{m_1}{m_2})}=\frac 12$

Intuitively, think in terms of concentration. Think of a vial of liquid with, say 30% concentration of a product, and another one with 35%. Mixing the two will never yield something with a concentration above 35% or below 30%.